# Specific wildcard pattern doesn't work in my struts.xml

Tags: struts2, wildcard, xml-configuration

I have an application in struts 2.3 and handled all requests by '/*' pattern to go to my struts application in web.xml
it's ok and requests are comes in struts application.
but problem is here in my **struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

   <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
   <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>

   <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="en/*" class="ir.mr.khatami.action.SensationalRequestAction" method="respond">
        <param name="locale">en</param>
        <result name="reload">pages/sensational.jsp</result>
      </action>

   </package>

</struts>
```

**in Web.xml i have**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

urls : localhost:8080/en , localhost:8080/en123 are ok

but i want something like this :

localhost:8080/en/something

and

localhost:8080/en/something/more

also i tried en** and /en** and /en/** but no result.

**this is error i recieved on this url localhost:8080/en/something**

**HTTP Status 404 - /exciting/en/pages/sensational.jsp** // exciting is root in my app.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Read http://struts.apache.org/docs/namespace-configuration.html and http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Parametersaftertheactionname.

Comment: @AleksandrM Can you please update the link, both links shows `404 Page Not Found`?

Answer (score 1):

Please review

https://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

The advanced title mention:

> From 2.1.9+ regular expressions can be defined defined in the action
>   name. To use this form of wild card, the following constants must be
>   set:
>
> ```
> <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
> <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
> <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
> ```

So your mapping must be

```
<action name="en/{type}" ...
```

You can read the `type` value in your action by simply adding `String type` with setter and getters.

PS: I can not test it right now but it seems to work

Comment: actually type don't needed to be stored some where. i just wanted to localize my site from any url after /en .

Comment: `<package name="action" namespace="/" extends="rest-default,json-default">
<action name="/{uid}/hello/{id}" class="com.wildcard.action.HelloController">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"/>
            <result type="json"/>
        </action></package>` I have this in my struts.xml, along with the xml tag for patternMatcher with the value of regex. But I get the error `There is no Action mapped for action name 2` when I access using the URL `http://localhost:8080/wildcard_sample/2/hello/3.json`. I am using `Struts 2.5.29`. @Alireza